# Facebook like Button is sending URL in place of Title

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-like

I am trying to send the Title information in the Facebook but on clikcing the Like button is sending URL in place of title.

My sample HTML is underneath

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPNetDB.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="url info" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="image url" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none;
            overflow: hidden; width: 260px; height: 35px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://localhost:49334/WebForm1.aspx&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=35">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?

Note - **This is my test application. I don't have publicly exposed IP address.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send the metadata to Facebook, Facebook retrieves the metadata from the page's HTML when it loads the page. Try viewing your URL with the following tool:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=<your URL here>
```

It will show you what Facebook sees (it's the 'Scraped URL' link at the bottom of the debug tool that you're using now).

If it does not include the metadata tags then Facebook does not see them and it won't add the metadata to its Open Graph object. If that's the case then you might not be adding the metadata properly to the HTML.

---

**Edit I :**  *"This is my test application. I don't have publicly exposed IP address."*

You **MUST** have publicly IP address, you can try :

- [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/)
- [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/)
- [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)
- [TZO](http://www.tzo.com/)
- [EasyDNS](http://web.easydns.com/)

---

**Edit II :** *I assumed Windows Host, If other please mention me*

This's [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) tutorials Youtube [Channel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FD4B5695C21E828), another [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/) Youtube [Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/noipDDNS), [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) related [Tutorials](http://www.opendns.com/support/videos/) and [TZO](http://www.tzo.com/) Tutorial [Page](http://www.tzo.com/MainPageSupport/TutorialsPage.html).

Comment: This is my test application. I don't have publicly exposed IP address.

Comment: „I don't have publicly exposed IP address” – then Facebook can’t scrape your URL, and has no _chance_ of reading your meta elements. Try using a DynDNS account or something to make your test machine reachable from the internet.

Comment: can you give some link on how to use these?